# Windows XP Loading Problem

Tags: windows-xp, windows-explorer

Sometimes, my Windows XP does not load correctly. It shows the login screen, and when I click my username, it load the desktop background, but the Explorer does not show up. So, I cannot see the icons on the desktop, the start menu, etc.

If I press Ctrl+Alt+Del to show Task Manager, I can run programs (like media player or browser) from File-->New Task (Run...).

Also, in the Task Manager, I see Explorer.exe running. I tried to kill and re-run it, but nothing happens.

I used Sysinternals Process Explorer to see if there were any odd process or odd behavior, but nothing was fishy.

After several restarts, the system finally worked as expected. But this is not permanent: Sometimes, when I restart the system, it works just as described above (Explorer does not show up). But sometimes it works normally.

I used Kaspersky to search for viruses, but nothing showed up.

> I think the info presented above is not enough to pinpoint the problem. Yet you might be able to tell me about a tool or something, which I can use to give you more info, or even solve the problem.

**PS:** I can easily use the Safe Mode. It does not seem to suffer from this problem. Hence, I suspect there's some process (service) for which Explorer is waiting, but that process runs into trouble (say a race ondition, or an infinite loop) and so Explorer stalls as well.

Comment: Run a chkdsk on the hard drive

Comment: @Moab: Thanks, but chkdsk didn't solve the issue. I ran "chkdsk /F C:" and it required a restart (since C: is locked). After a restart, Windows ran the scheduled chkdsk. It didn't find any problems. chkdsk then restarted the system. Finally, the logon screen appeared and I logged in, but the Explorer stalled again.

Comment: I would run a memory tester...http://www.memtest.org/  ....


Download the prebuilt ISO, burn it to CD as an Image (not data), boot from that CD and run the memory test for a couple of hours or overnight to stress test the memory.

Comment: @Moab: Thanks again. It's hard to believe that memory modules got corrupted, but nothing's impossible, so I'll give it a try. Meanwhile, any other suggestions are welcome. I'm specially interested in a tool that profiles the system startup and notices odd behavior of services.

Comment: See this article on enabling boot logging...http://www.msigeek.com/6231/how-to-enable-system-boot-time-logging-using-process-monitor-tool

Comment: @Moab: Thank you. This seems to be the best suggestion. I'll check and tell ya.

Comment: Also see these suggestions...http://www.thewindowsclub.com/explorer-exe-wont-start-at-boot-in-windows

Comment: Also create a New user account, log into the new user account and if the problem is gone, you have a corrupt user account.

Answer (score 0):

A possibility - for which I can offer no evidence - is that you have a virus that is hanging on start up. Virus scanners don't detect all viruses. You could try some other of the free scanners to see if they detect something. If they don't, then they are simple enough to remove afterwards.